Can't get the official AWS-CLI Docker image working
I have a Dockerfile that is literally just (I've also tried with only the first line as well):
FROM amazon/aws-cli:latest
CMD [ "sleep", "10000" ]

I build with:
docker build -t image-name .

I run with:
docker run -d --name container-name image-name

When I view the logs of the container this is what is shown:
2024-04-11 12:36:48 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
2024-04-11 12:36:48 To see help text, you can run:
2024-04-11 12:36:48 
2024-04-11 12:36:48   aws help
2024-04-11 12:36:48   aws <command> help
2024-04-11 12:36:48   aws <command> <subcommand> help
2024-04-11 12:36:48 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
2024-04-11 12:36:48 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 accessanalyzer                           | account                                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 acm                                      | acm-pca                                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 alexaforbusiness                         | amp                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 amplify                                  | amplifybackend                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 amplifyuibuilder                         | apigateway                              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 apigatewaymanagementapi                  | apigatewayv2                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 appconfig                                | appconfigdata                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 appfabric                                | appflow                                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 appintegrations                          | application-autoscaling                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 application-insights                     | applicationcostprofiler                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 appmesh                                  | apprunner                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 appstream                                | appsync                                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 arc-zonal-shift                          | artifact                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 athena                                   | auditmanager                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 autoscaling                              | autoscaling-plans                       
2024-04-11 12:36:48 b2bi                                     | backup                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 backup-gateway                           | backupstorage                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 batch                                    | bcm-data-exports                        
2024-04-11 12:36:48 bedrock                                  | bedrock-agent                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 bedrock-agent-runtime                    | bedrock-runtime                         
2024-04-11 12:36:48 billingconductor                         | braket                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 budgets                                  | ce                                      
2024-04-11 12:36:48 chatbot                                  | chime                                   
2024-04-11 12:36:48 chime-sdk-identity                       | chime-sdk-media-pipelines               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 chime-sdk-meetings                       | chime-sdk-messaging                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 chime-sdk-voice                          | cleanrooms                              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cleanroomsml                             | cloud9                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cloudcontrol                             | clouddirectory                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cloudformation                           | cloudfront                              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cloudfront-keyvaluestore                 | cloudhsm                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cloudhsmv2                               | cloudsearch                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cloudsearchdomain                        | cloudtrail                              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cloudtrail-data                          | cloudwatch                              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 codeartifact                             | codebuild                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 codecatalyst                             | codecommit                              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 codeconnections                          | codeguru-reviewer                       
2024-04-11 12:36:48 codeguru-security                        | codeguruprofiler                        
2024-04-11 12:36:48 codepipeline                             | codestar                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 codestar-connections                     | codestar-notifications                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cognito-identity                         | cognito-idp                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cognito-sync                             | comprehend                              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 comprehendmedical                        | compute-optimizer                       
2024-04-11 12:36:48 connect                                  | connect-contact-lens                    
2024-04-11 12:36:48 connectcampaigns                         | connectcases                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 connectparticipant                       | controlcatalog                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 controltower                             | cost-optimization-hub                   
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cur                                      | customer-profiles                       
2024-04-11 12:36:48 databrew                                 | dataexchange                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 datapipeline                             | datasync                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 datazone                                 | dax                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 deadline                                 | detective                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 devicefarm                               | devops-guru                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 directconnect                            | discovery                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 dlm                                      | dms                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 docdb                                    | docdb-elastic                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 drs                                      | ds                                      
2024-04-11 12:36:48 dynamodb                                 | dynamodbstreams                         
2024-04-11 12:36:48 ebs                                      | ec2                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 ec2-instance-connect                     | ecr                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 ecr-public                               | ecs                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 efs                                      | eks                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 eks-auth                                 | elastic-inference                       
2024-04-11 12:36:48 elasticache                              | elasticbeanstalk                        
2024-04-11 12:36:48 elastictranscoder                        | elb                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 elbv2                                    | emr                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 emr-containers                           | emr-serverless                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 entityresolution                         | es                                      
2024-04-11 12:36:48 events                                   | evidently                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 finspace                                 | finspace-data                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 firehose                                 | fis                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 fms                                      | forecast                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 forecastquery                            | frauddetector                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 freetier                                 | fsx                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 gamelift                                 | glacier                                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 globalaccelerator                        | glue                                    
2024-04-11 12:36:48 grafana                                  | greengrass                              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 greengrassv2                             | groundstation                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 guardduty                                | health                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 healthlake                               | honeycode                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 iam                                      | identitystore                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 imagebuilder                             | importexport                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 inspector                                | inspector-scan                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 inspector2                               | internetmonitor                         
2024-04-11 12:36:48 iot                                      | iot-data                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 iot-jobs-data                            | iot1click-devices                       
2024-04-11 12:36:48 iot1click-projects                       | iotanalytics                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 iotdeviceadvisor                         | iotevents                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 iotevents-data                           | iotfleethub                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 iotfleetwise                             | iotsecuretunneling                      
2024-04-11 12:36:48 iotsitewise                              | iotthingsgraph                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 iottwinmaker                             | iotwireless                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 ivs                                      | ivs-realtime                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 ivschat                                  | kafka                                   
2024-04-11 12:36:48 kafkaconnect                             | kendra                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 kendra-ranking                           | keyspaces                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 kinesis                                  | kinesis-video-archived-media            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 kinesis-video-media                      | kinesis-video-signaling                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 kinesis-video-webrtc-storage             | kinesisanalytics                        
2024-04-11 12:36:48 kinesisanalyticsv2                       | kinesisvideo                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 kms                                      | lakeformation                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 lambda                                   | launch-wizard                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 lex-models                               | lex-runtime                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 lexv2-models                             | lexv2-runtime                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 license-manager                          | license-manager-linux-subscriptions     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 license-manager-user-subscriptions       | lightsail                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 location                                 | logs                                    
2024-04-11 12:36:48 lookoutequipment                         | lookoutmetrics                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 lookoutvision                            | m2                                      
2024-04-11 12:36:48 machinelearning                          | macie2                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 managedblockchain                        | managedblockchain-query                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 marketplace-agreement                    | marketplace-catalog                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 marketplace-deployment                   | marketplace-entitlement                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 marketplacecommerceanalytics             | mediaconnect                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 mediaconvert                             | medialive                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 mediapackage                             | mediapackage-vod                        
2024-04-11 12:36:48 mediapackagev2                           | mediastore                              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 mediastore-data                          | mediatailor                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 medical-imaging                          | memorydb                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 meteringmarketplace                      | mgh                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 mgn                                      | migration-hub-refactor-spaces           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 migrationhub-config                      | migrationhuborchestrator                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 migrationhubstrategy                     | mobile                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 mq                                       | mturk                                   
2024-04-11 12:36:48 mwaa                                     | neptune                                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 neptune-graph                            | neptunedata                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 network-firewall                         | networkmanager                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 networkmonitor                           | nimble                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 oam                                      | omics                                   
2024-04-11 12:36:48 opensearch                               | opensearchserverless                    
2024-04-11 12:36:48 opsworks                                 | opsworkscm                              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 organizations                            | osis                                    
2024-04-11 12:36:48 outposts                                 | panorama                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 payment-cryptography                     | payment-cryptography-data               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 pca-connector-ad                         | personalize                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 personalize-events                       | personalize-runtime                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 pi                                       | pinpoint                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 pinpoint-email                           | pinpoint-sms-voice                      
2024-04-11 12:36:48 pinpoint-sms-voice-v2                    | pipes                                   
2024-04-11 12:36:48 polly                                    | pricing                                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 privatenetworks                          | proton                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 qbusiness                                | qconnect                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 qldb                                     | qldb-session                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 quicksight                               | ram                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 rbin                                     | rds                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 rds-data                                 | redshift                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 redshift-data                            | redshift-serverless                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 rekognition                              | repostspace                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 resiliencehub                            | resource-explorer-2                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 resource-groups                          | resourcegroupstaggingapi                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 robomaker                                | rolesanywhere                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 route53                                  | route53-recovery-cluster                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 route53-recovery-control-config          | route53-recovery-readiness              
2024-04-11 12:36:48 route53domains                           | route53resolver                         
2024-04-11 12:36:48 rum                                      | s3control                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 s3outposts                               | sagemaker                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 sagemaker-a2i-runtime                    | sagemaker-edge                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 sagemaker-featurestore-runtime           | sagemaker-geospatial                    
2024-04-11 12:36:48 sagemaker-metrics                        | sagemaker-runtime                       
2024-04-11 12:36:48 savingsplans                             | scheduler                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 schemas                                  | sdb                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 secretsmanager                           | securityhub                             
2024-04-11 12:36:48 securitylake                             | serverlessrepo                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 service-quotas                           | servicecatalog                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 servicecatalog-appregistry               | servicediscovery                        
2024-04-11 12:36:48 ses                                      | sesv2                                   
2024-04-11 12:36:48 shield                                   | signer                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 simspaceweaver                           | sms                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 snow-device-management                   | snowball                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 sns                                      | sqs                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 ssm                                      | ssm-contacts                            
2024-04-11 12:36:48 ssm-incidents                            | ssm-sap                                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 sso                                      | sso-admin                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 sso-oidc                                 | stepfunctions                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 storagegateway                           | sts                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 supplychain                              | support                                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 support-app                              | swf                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 synthetics                               | textract                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 timestream-influxdb                      | timestream-query                        
2024-04-11 12:36:48 timestream-write                         | tnb                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 transcribe                               | transfer                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 translate                                | trustedadvisor                          
2024-04-11 12:36:48 verifiedpermissions                      | voice-id                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 vpc-lattice                              | waf                                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 waf-regional                             | wafv2                                   
2024-04-11 12:36:48 wellarchitected                          | wisdom                                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 workdocs                                 | worklink                                
2024-04-11 12:36:48 workmail                                 | workmailmessageflow                     
2024-04-11 12:36:48 workspaces                               | workspaces-thin-client                  
2024-04-11 12:36:48 workspaces-web                           | xray                                    
2024-04-11 12:36:48 s3api                                    | s3                                      
2024-04-11 12:36:48 ddb                                      | configure                               
2024-04-11 12:36:48 deploy                                   | configservice                           
2024-04-11 12:36:48 opsworks-cm                              | history                                 
2024-04-11 12:36:48 cli-dev                                  | help                                    
2024-04-11 12:36:48 

...which is normally what appears when you attempt an incorrect aws command like this for example:
aws aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Can anyone please help me out? I don't know if there's something I'm missing, but I'm really confused as to why this isn't working. Thank you!
---
I've also tried installing the AWS-CLI in the container per these instructions but had no luck and ran into issues like this when running many commands:
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
dpkg: warning: 'diff' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

...even though my Path is set properly

It seems like you're trying to prevent the container from doing anything; what benefit do you have from a container running a sleep command?  Your actual problem is that the base image declares ENTRYPOINT ["aws"] and so it doesn't run normal shell commands, but you should be able to docker run --rm ... amazon/aws-cli sts get-caller-identity to run one-off commands, using the CLI, with some tricky problems around access to credentials that live only on your host system.

Amazon cli image doesn't work with Gitlab CI covers a similar case, this one related to repeating aws in the command part.

Thank you for your response! I was trying to use the aws-cli image but was getting this issue, so I stripped my Dockerfile down to what it is for the sake of fixing this problem. Once it's resolved I'll do something with my container.
So basically I need to change the entrypoint? What do I change it to? I'm sorry I'm not really following everything you said and everything in that other question/answer.

Wait I got it thank you so much! Had to add ENTRYPOINT [""] to my Dockerfile and build and run again.

This is because the image you grabbed in the docker FROM directive makes use of entrypoint (see https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#entrypoint)
Try doing the run like so instead:
docker run -d --entrypoint /bin/bash --name container-name image-name

Remove the -d flag to test it out.
Or modify your docker file like so (i haven't tested this tho):
# modified as per @David Maze's comment
FROM amazon/aws-cli:latest
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD [ "sleep", "10000" ]


When I try your run command in Git Bash (both with and without the -d flag) it returns:
"docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "C:/dev/git/usr/bin/bash": stat C:/dev/git/usr/bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown."
When I try in PowerShell it returns nothing. In every case the logs are completely blank and the container ends immediately.

(ENTRYPOINT needs to be in JSON-array syntax, or else it ignores the CMD.  I'm not sure why the container would need to run either bash or sleep.)

Per David Maze's responses, "the base image declares ENTRYPOINT ["aws"] and so it doesn't run normal shell commands", the solution was to change my Dockerfile like this:
FROM amazon/aws-cli:latest
ENTRYPOINT [""]
CMD [ "sleep", "10000" ]

